# How do I combine multiple function calls with recompose?

Tags: reactjs, recompose

I have a function in my class component that I want to refactor using recompose:

```
handleSelected = lang => {
    this.setState({
        selected: lang
    })
    fetchPopularRepos(lang).then(repos => {
        this.setState({
            selected: lang,
            repos
        })
    })
}
```

---

```
const handleSelected = props => lang => {
        this.setState({
            selected: lang,
            repos: null
        })
        fetchPopularRepos(lang).then(repos => this.setState({ repos }))
    }

const withPopularReposState = withStateHandlers(initialState, {
    handleSelected
})
```

Of course this doesn't work and I get an error `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`. How do I combine multiple function calls with recompose?